# How to submit contact us data to Magento 2 contact us form action using graphqL?

Tags: contact-us, contact-form, magento2.3.2, graphql

How to submit contact us form data to Magento default functionalities using graphQl.
I know to want to pass the form data using **Mutation** and doesn't have a clear idea to achieve the target.

Please kindly help me in this.

Answer (score 3):

Since we don't have default contact us mutation in default magento graphql,
I did this task with a custom module.
For this we want to create the custom contact us Mutation.

```
type Mutation {
contactusFormSubmit(input: ContactusInput!): ContactusOutput @resolver(class: "\\Ayakil\\ContactUs\\Model\\Resolver\\Contactus") @doc(description:"Contact us form")
}

input ContactusInput {
fullname: String @doc(description: "The customer's full name")
email: String @doc(description: "The customer's email address")
telephone: String @doc(description: "The Telephone")
message: String @doc(description: "The customer's message")
}

type ContactusOutput {
success_message: String @doc(description: "Success Message")
}
```

Want to capture the from the form and pass it to resolver through Mutation.

My resolver file.

```
<?php
namespace Ayakil\ContactUs\Model\Resolver;
//resolver section
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

class Contactus implements ResolverInterface
{
private $contactusDataProvider;

/**
 * @param
 */
public function __construct(
    \Ayakil\ContactUs\Model\Resolver\DataProvider\Contactus $contactusDataProvider
) {
    $this->contactusDataProvider = $contactusDataProvider;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function resolve(
    Field $field,
    $context,
    ResolveInfo $info,
    array $value = null,
    array $args = null
) {
    $fullname = $args['input']['fullname'];
    $email = $args['input']['email'];
    $telephone = $args['input']['telephone'];
    $message = $args['input']['message'];

    $success_message = $this->contactusDataProvider->contactUs(
        $fullname,
        $email,
        $telephone,
        $message
    );
    return $success_message;
}
}
```

After this want to pass the data to data provider file.

```
<?php
namespace Ayakil\ContactUs\Model\Resolver\DataProvider;
//contact us section 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface; 
use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface; 
use Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface; 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context; 
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface; 
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect; 
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException; 
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Contactus
{
private $dataPersistor;
private $mail;
private $formKey;


public function __construct(
    ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
    MailInterface $mail,
    DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey
) {
    $this->mail = $mail;
    $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
}

public function contactUs($fullname,$email,$subject,$message){
    $thanks_message = [];
    try {
        $this->sendEmail($fullname,$email,$subject,$message);
    }catch (LocalizedException $e) { }
    $thanks_message['success_message']="Thanks For Contacting Us";
    return $thanks_message;
}

private function sendEmail($fullname,$email,$telephone,$message)
{
    $form_data = [];
    $form_data['name']      =   $fullname;
    $form_data['email']     =   $email;
    $form_data['telephone'] =   $telephone;
    $form_data['comment']   =   $message;
    $form_data['hideit']    =   "";
    $form_data['form_key']  =   $this->getFormKey();

    $this->mail->send(
        $email,
        ['data' => new DataObject($form_data)]
    );
}

public function getFormKey()
{
    return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
}
}
```

After completing this i have wrote a descriptive article about this topic in my blog.Please visit [How to write grapgQl mutation to create and integrate the contact us page functionality in magento 2.3.2?](https://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-write-grapgql-mutation-to-create-and-integrate-the-contact-us-page-functionality-in-magento-2-3-2/)